# Why does GetFileVersionInfo on kernel32.dll in Windows 10 return version 6.2?

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-10, kernel32

I am trying to retrieve `kernel32.dll` version in order to perform a Windows version check. Yet, for some reason, even though `kernel32.dll`'s version (as seen in file properties) is 10.0.10586.0, the returned version is: 6.2.10586.0
how come?

```
    DWORD dwDummy;
    DWORD dwFVISize = GetFileVersionInfoSize(lpszFilePath, &dwDummy);
    LPBYTE lpVersionInfo = new BYTE[dwFVISize];
    if (GetFileVersionInfo(lpszFilePath, 0, dwFVISize, lpVersionInfo) == 0)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    UINT uLen;
    VS_FIXEDFILEINFO *lpFfi;
    BOOL bVer = VerQueryValue(lpVersionInfo, L"\\", (LPVOID *)&lpFfi, &uLen);

    if (!bVer || uLen == 0)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    DWORD dwFileVersionMS = lpFfi->dwFileVersionMS;
    DWORD dwFileVersionLS = lpFfi->dwFileVersionLS;
    delete[] lpVersionInfo;

    DWORD dwLeftMost = HIWORD(dwFileVersionMS);
    DWORD dwSecondLeft = LOWORD(dwFileVersionMS);
    DWORD dwSecondRight = HIWORD(dwFileVersionLS);
    DWORD dwRightMost = LOWORD(dwFileVersionLS);
```

Kernel32.dll properties (same as in SysWow64):
[image]

Comment: Build your app as a 64 bit executable and see if you get the same result.

Comment: See [how to detect windows 10 in c++](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36543301/1889329) for an alternate approach.

Comment: "in order to perform a windows version check." - fastest and most effective use RtlGetNtVersionNumbers for this

Comment: @RbMm: `RtlGetNtVersionNumbers` is undocumented. It is not part of the public programming interface, and may not be available in a future version of the OS. Why not recommend [RtlGetVersion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff561910.aspx) instead? At least that's documented (even though calling a kernel-mode routine from user-mode may not be supported in a future OS as well).

Comment: @IInspectable yes, RtlGetVersion also good choice for determinate os version number(both in kernel and user mode). when i wrote about RtlGetNtVersionNumbers - this was not recommendation, but this function is absolute fastest and lightweight way for get version numbers only. not public programming interface ? but exported. about undocumented - util this is exist and not changed from xp(think and in win2000 but cannot check) to win 10 latest build. visa versa GetVersion[Ex] is well documented, but it behavior is changed - so now it can not correct work in 8.1 and 10.

Comment: @RbMm: Programming isn't about statistics. Just because an API hasn't changed in *<insert random period>* doesn't mean that it won't go away at *<insert random future date>*. Better performance is not ever a valid reason to ignore a documented API. If you don't care about correctness it is trivially easy to improve the performance (by omitting the call altogether).

Comment: This code will leak memory if `VerQueryValue` fails, due to the early return just before freeing `lpVersionInfo`. Not a big deal really, just wanted to point it out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are reading the wrong fields from the version information for this task. Instead of `dwFileVersionMS` and `dwFileVersionLS` use `dwProductVersionMS` and `dwProductVersionLS`.

The file version fields are subject to `supportedOS` compatibility issues. That is their values depend on the `supportedOS` levels declared in your application manifest. On the other hand the product version fields do not depend on the manifest.

Comment: is it relevant even though the file version is the same as the product version? I am trying it now.

Comment: Your code yields 6.2 when I run it, but 10.0 when you use the correct fields.

Comment: You should really have pulled this out into a separate [mcve]. That would have made it easier for all of us to investigate, you included.

Comment: " wrong fields" - dwFileVersionMS not wrong field, but it can be "fixed" . dwProductVersionMS - not fixed now (before "fix" dwFileVersionMS==dwProductVersionMS)

Comment: @RbMm They are the wrong fields in the sense that the asker is, presumably, looking for the true version rather than the compat version. I mean, otherwise the asker would just call `GetVersionEx`.

Comment: "in order to perform a windows version check." - need at all another API use.

Comment: @RbMm I don't understand that comment at all. Do you understand why people check product version of a system DLL?

Comment: yes, author want perform a windows version check. but selected way for this - not very good, from my look. the absolut fastest and universal way(work from xp up to latest win10) - ULONG Major, Minor, Build;
  RtlGetNtVersionNumbers(&Major, &Minor, &Build); - here near 10 asm instructions only, in compare with many many thousands with check version fron file(and why kernel32 ?)

Comment: I think that perhaps you should take that up with the asker rather than commenting on my answer, which after all just addressed the question that was asked. Remember to mention that `RtlGetNtVersionNumbers` is an undocumented API that might not exist in a future release. Note also that the asker is doing what MS suggest: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724429(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Which says: *To obtain the full version number for the operating system, call the GetFileVersionInfo function on one of the system DLLs, such as Kernel32.dll, then call VerQueryValue to obtain the \\StringFileInfo\\<lang><codepage>\\ProductVersion subblock of the file version information.* Finally, I don't imagine that this code is really going to be a performance bottleneck.

Answer (score 6):

> Applications not manifested for Windows 8.1 or Windows 10 will return
>   the Windows 8 OS version value (6.2).

this is from GetVersionEx function MSDN description. for GetFileVersionInfo no such note, but really this doing same. i look under debugger:
[image]

[image]

so 10.0 ( 0xA000) in dwFileVersionMS can be fixed to 6.2 or 6.3 
but dwProductVersionMS - not changed (0xA000 ~ 10.0)
think need fix MSDN documentation for GetFileVersionInfo[Ex] :)

Comment: Which is this debugger that you are using? Can you also write steps you performed?

Comment: @SahilSingh - my own.