# Detecting Windows 10 OS Build minor version

Tags: windows-10, wdk

I've created a Bluetooth low-energy library, that due to [an issue with Windows 10 Version 1709](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dccd9101-d28a-4073-b209-19ffd16bb10f/bluetooth-le-device-stopped-connecting-in-windows-10-v1709?forum=wdk), only works for OS Build 16299.125 and above (fixed in the [KB4054517](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/4054517) update). For earlier versions, it causes to BLE device to misbehave and give false connection indications.

Thus, I wish to check for the existence of this update on the client machine, and 
prevent the library from running if the version is too low.

I've followed [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36545162/499721), and used [`RtlGetVersion()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff561910.aspx) to get the OS version. However, as far as I can tell, no field in the returned structure contains the minor part of the build version (e.g. '125' in '16299.125'), AKA 'Update Build Revision' or UBR.

This is true even when calling `RtlGetVersion()` with the extended structure ([`RTL_OSVERSIONINFOEXW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff563620.aspx)).

Is there a reliable way of getting the minor version of the OS build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This UBR value is stored in Registry under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion` in a DWORD [which you can query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35717/1466046)

[image]

Comment: Is `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion.UBR` a formal Windows API (or close enough)?

Comment: this is defined in winnt.h: UNIFIEDBUILDREVISION_KEY L"\\Registry\\Machine\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion", UNIFIEDBUILDREVISION_VALUE                      L"UBR"

Comment: great! just what I was looking for.