# C# - How to show the full Windows 10 build number?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-10

How to show the full Windows 10 build on C#?

I'm currently using `Environment.OSVersion.VersionString` but it's not showing the full build number

The result:

> Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.17134.0

But I want the last number, my full build: 10.0.17134.**228**

I want to know how can I show the last missing number. Not only where to find the number. The c# code to get it.

Comment: [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.osversion?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks) say: 'Starting with Windows 8, the OSVersion property returns the same major and minor version numbers for all Windows platforms. Therefore, we do not recommend that you retrieve the value of this property to determine the operating system version.'

Comment: What do you recommend to check if the user is using the latest Windows version/build? The first 17134 version was released on April, but Microsoft released 9 new builds of it, how can I check if the user is using the latest one?

Comment: Sorry friend, i dont have a clue. Just stumbled over that link and wanted to share that information =)

Comment: P-Invoke GetVersionEx - see [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8406674/20257)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting Windows 10 OS Build minor version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47926094/detecting-windows-10-os-build-minor-version)

Comment: @magicandre1981 no. It's not related to c# .net commands

Comment: this makes no difference, it is the same question about getting the Revision number.

Comment: I included more details to explain that I want to know how to show not only how to find it. The c# command of it. @Lews Therin did that on his answer, added not only where but how to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Windows 10 build number [is stored in the registry](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/23975-find-windows-10-build-number.html) in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\` in the `UBR` key.

Here's how to get it in code:

```
using Microsoft.Win32;

// ...

RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion");

var buildNumber = registryKey.GetValue("UBR").ToString();
```

**EDIT**: Fixed the value name to get the correct number for OP. Credit for the correct key to Jorge Aguiar.

Comment: Didn't work, it showed me: 17134, I'm looking for the 228 value. After the current build.

Comment: Fixed to the correct key identified by Jorge Aguiar. This should get you what you need @saulob.

Comment: It's "using Microsoft.Win32" not "using Microsoft.Windows", I edited :)

Answer (score 3):

You can get the last missing number at

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\UBR

(it's a DWORD value. It might be missing in some Windows versions.)

Comment: You want the `CurrentBuild` value.

Comment: @LewsTherin no, the `CurrentBuild`value, in the provided example, contains 17134, not 228.

Comment: My mistake, Jorge is correct. This will get OP the number he wants.

Comment: @LewsTherin he's trying to get the number _after_ the `CurrentBuild`, in his example it's 228, which is stored in the registry key I mentioned

Comment: Yes, and I fixed my answer and made a comment acknowledging you had the correct key. My bad.

Comment: Correct, combined with my parts of my answer - The code to obtain the number is: `Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion").GetValue("UBR");`

Answer (score 1):

You've to combine the 2 values to get "OS build":

```
RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion");

var _UBR = registryKey.GetValue("UBR").ToString();
var _CurrentBuild = registryKey.GetValue("CurrentBuild").ToString();

string _version = _CurrentBuild+"."+ _UBR;
```

Answer (score 1):

Cheesy way to get what you're asking for:

```
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe",
            Arguments = "/c ver",
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            UseShellExecute = false
        }).StandardOutput.ReadToEnd().Trim();
```

Returns a string like:
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1052]