# Problem getting full version number for Windows 10 with GetFileVersionInfo and VerQueryValue

Tags: c, winapi

I want to get the full version number for Windows, just like CMD does:

[image: Full version number from console]

I ended up with this [MS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sysinfo/getting-the-system-version) that says:

> To obtain the full version number for the operating system, call the
>   GetFileVersionInfo function on one of the system DLLs, such as
>   Kernel32.dll, then call VerQueryValue to obtain the
>   \StringFileInfo\\ProductVersion subblock of the file version
>   information.

So I tried to use those functions with this code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <wchar.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Mincore.lib")

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    // GetFileVersionInfoW
    LPCWSTR fileName = L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\kernel32.dll";
    DWORD fileInfoSize;

    fileInfoSize = GetFileVersionInfoSizeW(fileName, NULL);

    if (fileInfoSize == 0)
    {
        fwprintf(stderr, L"\nError code: %u\n", GetLastError());
        return;
    }

    // GetFileVersionInfoW
    VOID* pFileVerInfo = malloc(fileInfoSize);

    if (pFileVerInfo == NULL)
    {
        fwprintf(stderr, L"Failed allocating!\n");
        return;
    }

    if (!GetFileVersionInfoW(fileName, 0, fileInfoSize, pFileVerInfo))
    {
        fwprintf(stderr, L"Error code: %u\n", GetLastError());
        free(pFileVerInfo);
        return;
    }

    // VerQueryValueW
    LPCWSTR subBlock = L"\\StringFileInfo\\\\ProductVersion";
    VS_FIXEDFILEINFO * pFileInfo;
    UINT pLen = 0;

    if (!VerQueryValueW(pFileVerInfo, subBlock, (LPVOID*)& pFileInfo, &pLen))
    {
        fwprintf(stderr, L"Error code: %u\n", GetLastError());
        return;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

However, the `VerQueryValueW` function fails with code `1813` and I have no idea why. I also have no idea how I can show the full version after calling the function.

Can you help me?

Comment: Try outputting different text for the different failure cases... you can't tell whether it was `GetFileVersionInfoSizeW` that failed, or `GetFileVersionInfoW`, or `VerQueryValueW`

Comment: Well... I set some breakpoints from within Visual Studio and turns out that `VerQueryValueW` is the one who is failing.

Comment: `return;` is illegal in function returning `int`

Comment: You should look at [this question instead](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36543301/62576) rather than jumping through hoops.

Comment: Error 1813 is ["The specified resource type cannot be found in the image file."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/system-error-codes--1700-3999-)

Comment: maybe you also have to get the right region code; on my other working file `\\StringFileInfo\\040904E4\\ProductVersion` works, but it fails to omit the region code

Comment: Yes you will need the region code as @M.M suggests. You can get it from `\\VarFileInfo\\Translation`. Or, just read the `VS_FIXEDFILEINFO` structure instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`L"\\StringFileInfo\\\\ProductVersion"` is not correct. There must be a Language ID in the middle.  On my Windows 10 installation, a working string is: `L"\\StringFileInfo\\040904B0\\ProductVersion"`.  But maybe this would differ on other systems.

As suggested by Jonathan Potter in comments, you could find the ID by querying `\\VarFileInfo\\Translation`.

---

Simpler options to achieve the goal include:

- [Query `VS_FIXEDFILEINFO`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/940707/1505939) instead of `StringFileInfo`
- [Read the OS version from the Windows API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36543301/detecting-windows-10-version) instead of querying a random DLL.